# Javascript: Get current path and remove the 'm.' at start of url when user wants to go to main site

Tags: jquery, url, mobile, jquery-mobile, strip

I have created a mobile site (with the help of jquery mobile) and one of the footer links is 'Full site'.

When a user clicks this I want them to go to the same page they are currently on but on the main site (i.e. not just loading home page).

The mobile site = m.xxxxxx.com
The main site is = xxxxxx.com

I know I can get the current url via:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

But then how do i strip the 'm.' at the beginning?

A.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys but I cant seem to get these working with jquery mobiles default ajax navigation

Answer (score 1):

window.location.pathname returns the path after the domain

ie if it is http://www.example.com/test.php?id=1 window.location.pathname will return /test.php?id=1

so use

```
var pathname = "http://" + location.host.replace('m.','') + window.location.pathname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`location.host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties):

```
$('#viewOnFullSite').click(function ()
{
    var re = /^m\./;
    if (re.test(location.host))
    {
        location.host = location.host.replace(re, '');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `substring` function of JavaScript. You can use

`window.location.pathname.substring(2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" id="fullsite">Full site</a>

$('#fullsite').attr('href', location.host.replace('m.','') + window.location.pathname;);
```